# Faster way to compute the probability of $x$-th permutation being something

Tags: probability

Say we have $12$ males and $24$ females

and we have to calculate the probability of the $2$nd person of being a male

we would do something like this

$(M)(M) + (F)(M)$

but what if we asked to calculate the probability of the $24$th person of being a male?

Is there a fast way to compute that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way. It is $\dfrac{12}{36}$.

The problem has not been fully described, but presumably we put these people in a row at random. All permutations are **equally likely**. So Adam, and Bob, and Charlie, and so on each have probability $\frac{1}{36}$ of being in any particular position, like the $24$-th, or the first.

Also, the probability that males occupy positions $5$ and $9$ and $17$ is the same as the probability they occupy positions $1$, $2$, and $3$.

We do have to be careful though. **Given** that the first person is male, the probability the $17$-th is male is $\frac{11}{35}$. Symmetrically, given that the $17$-th person is male, the probability the first is male is also $\frac{11}{35}$.

Comment: and how did you get that? is there a formula? or something? is there a theorem for this?

Comment: You would know how to find the probability the first is male. There are $36$ people, of whom $12$ are male, so the probability the first is male is $12/36$ (favourable divided by total). The probability the $24$-th is male is exactly the same, since all permutatios are equally likely.

Comment: ok equally likely is like saying "ball is replaced"?

Comment: sorry, for this dumb question, but is this elementary conditionnal probability?

Comment: No, it is **not** replaced, still equally likely. Please do me a favour. Calculate the probability the second is male the long way, two cases, (i) first is male, second male, and (ii) first is female, Then add up. You will get $12/36$. Now find the long way the probability the third is male. Four cases, MMM, MFM, FMM, FMF, FFM. Calculate the probabilities, add up. You will get $12/36$ (or $1/3$). If you are a masochist, do probability the fourth is male, the long way, $8$ cases, You will get $1/3$. If you do this work, you will  appreciate the all permutations equally likely viewpoint.

Comment: The long way described in previous comment is via conditional probabilities. I am assuming from your post you can handle that way, and you were asking whether there was a faster one. The answer is yes, much fster, indeed instant.

Comment: And the probability the 17th is male if the first and second is male is 10/34? k... I don't understand exactly how you got 12/36, I guess there is a theorem for that, but we will never cover it since it is obvious... so the probability the 5th, 6th or whatever is female is always 24/36?

Comment: Yes. I hope you do some of the longer (but not very long) calclations i suggested. It will help to persuade you. It takes a while until it becomes obvious.